# Geometric significance of 3 linear equations of three unknowns.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry, 3d

I am trying to learn the basic concepts of linear algebra and matrices.
What is the geometric significance of the equations?

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
    x + y + z = 2 \\
    x + 2y + z = 3 \\
    2x + 3y + 2z = 5 \\
\end{array}\right.$$

The first two equations add up to give the third one. But I do not know how they are related in terms of geometry.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Since the third equation is not unique, then basically you have just two equations here.... Two planes, but we can't represent in matrix

Comment: Linearly dependent third equation belongs to a plane going through intersection of first two planes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the equations describes a plane. Generally, three such equation describes the only point that belongs to those three planes. But since, in your case, the third equation adds no new information, what you have there describes that intersection of two distinct non-parallel planes, which is a line.

Comment: So, the first two equations intersect and the solution is that line. Does this line fall in the third equation? If x,y,z satisfy the first two equations, do they also satisfy the third equation in terms of 3d-geometry?

Comment: Yes (for both questions).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.